# Mock a class type argument with ArgumentsMatchers and Mockito - Mongo aggregation Spring Webflux

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-webflux

I have this call to MongoDB and I want to mock it.

```
private ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate;

...constructor

reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "foo_collection", FooData.class);
```

I tried with this but get a `NullPointerException`, always

```
Mockito.when(reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any()))
                .thenReturn(Flux.just(fooData));
```

I'm also tried with this and get the same error

```
Mockito.when(reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<FooData>>any())))
                .thenReturn(Flux.just(fooData));
```

Comment: Can you please share the complete TestClass and Class to be tested with Autowired dependencies especially ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using the mock like this:

```
 Mockito.when(reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(any(Aggregation.class), anyString(), eq(FooData.class)))
                .thenReturn(Flux.just(fooData));
```

Answer (score 0):

The mock seems to be correct, have you initialized `Mockito` in the test class?

```
public class TestClass {
    @Before
    public void initTest() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    //..
}
```

Or:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestClass {
    //...
}
```

Are you using `@Mock` to inject `ReactiveMongoTemplate` in the class test?

```
public class TestClass {
    @Mock
    private ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate;
    //..
}
```

Comment: Yes I've initialized with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and   `@Mock
    private ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate;`